# Apple Testflight: how to re-invite internal user after user stop test

Tags: xcode, testflight

one user  accept the testflight invite and stop it, but currently the user want to re-test app.

i already resend the testflight invite, but the user click the invite email, it not success and show the error. (refer the image)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjXzr.jpg)

any solution?

already try the below way but not work

- resend invite
- remove the user testing email in testflight (include internal testing / external testing etc)
- also remove the user developer role in the team

and then resend invite but still not work